# PDF to jpg conversion without ImageMagik

Tags: thumbnails

I have a client that is really wanting thumbnails of uploaded PDF files on their site. Unfortunately the host does not / will not support ImageMagik as part of their hosting. They do support GD but that's not helpful in this situation.

Has anybody run across this problem before? Any suggestions or recommendations? Almost every solution I come across for doing PDF > jpeg conversion involves ImageMagik.